# Use SIM module in HP 8440p Elite Book under Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, modem, mobile, telephony

How can I use SIM slot in HP 8440p Elite Book? I tried every thing on the Internet, but I can't use it.

I want to use it to send messages and calls, etc. I mean all SIM functions. I'm using Kali Linux 2.0 which is Debian based.

```
root@Unknown:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bb4:0ff9 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Desire / Desire HD / Hero / Thunderbolt (Charge Mode) 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 001 Device 003: ID 090c:037c Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 300k Pixel Camera 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Can you clarify some of the "everythings" that you've tried from the Internet?

Comment: i have tried installing fprint_demo and manny others

Comment: Try setup using mobile broad band or install driver